# HowTo make Xcode recognize custom templates

Tags: ios, xcode, viper-architecture

I've been using [Generamba](https://github.com/rambler-digital-solutions/Generamba) to create template files for each module under VIPER architecture for iOS.

It saves a lot of time, but still needs commands through terminal to run Generamba and create the files. Does anyone have a clue on how to embed those templates generated directly into XCode 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [templates inside Xcode](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-custom-xcode-templates) to generate your VIPER classes. Take a look on this [repository](https://github.com/natangr/ViperTemplate), it already implements the basic VIPER files for you.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with `Generamba`, but to make `Xcode` recognize your templates in general:

- put your `Template.swift` file in a folder called `MyTemplate.xctemplate`
- tell Xcode some details about your template by adding a `Templateinfo.plist` to `MyTemplate.xctemplate` (find example below).
- copy `MyTemplate.xctemplate` to `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File\ Templates/Custom`.

After doing so, the templates show up on the bottom of `Xcode`s `new File` template selection menu.

Example:

[image]

---

You can use environmental variable placeholders that get replaced by `Xcode`.

Here is a simple example template called `Worker.swift`:

```
//
//  ___FILENAME___
//  ___PROJECTNAME___
//
//  Created by ___FULLUSERNAME___ on ___DATE___.
//  Copyright (c) ___YEAR___ ___ORGANIZATIONNAME___. All rights reserved.
//
//  This file was generated. DO NOT MODIFY !
//

import Foundation

class ___FILEBASENAMEASIDENTIFIER___Worker {

    //implementation goes here
}
```

And its example `Templateinfo.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>DefaultCompletionName</key>
    <string>MyWorker</string>
    <key>Description</key>
    <string>This generates a new worker.</string>
    <key>Kind</key>
    <string>Xcode.IDEKit.TextSubstitutionFileTemplateKind</string>
    <key>Options</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Default</key>
            <string>___VARIABLE_sceneName:identifier___Worker</string>
            <key>Description</key>
            <string>The worker name</string>
            <key>Identifier</key>
            <string>workerName</string>
            <key>Name</key>
            <string>Worker Name:</string>
            <key>Required</key>
            <true/>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>static</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>Platforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.platform.iphoneos</string>
    </array>
    <key>SortOrder</key>
    <string>4</string>
    <key>Summary</key>
    <string>Summery</string>
</dict>
```

You can also place multiple files within your `MyTemplate.xctemplate` directory to make Xcode create multiple files at once. For your `VIPER` templates, you can make Xcode create a whole `VIPER` scene at once.

You can find working examples plus a  `makefile` [in this "Clean Swift" template repo](https://github.com/buffstop/TheWho/tree/master/Clean%20Swift) (Clean Swift is yet another Clean Architecture approach for Swift).

Comment: How to custom set the templates under the macOS section?

Comment: @A.C: I _think_ you can only create new sections.

Comment: Yes, I had create a new sections for macOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ViperC](https://github.com/abdullahselek/ViperC) it supports both **Objective-C** and **Swift**. Also you can create test classes for the modules you created. Test classes use `Quick` and `Expecta` for **Objective-C** and `Quick` and `Nimble` for **Swift**.